# Adding to Bootstrap container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to add a `div` with the class `.curtain` above my main `.container` class that is just slightly wider than the `.container`. What would be your approach to accomplishing that?

```
<div class="container curtain"></div>
<div class=" container">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of without knowing more detail about the question would be to add the following CSS:

```
.curtain{
   width:110%; 
}
```